# DRF returning model object in Response(serializer.data)

Tags: django-rest-framework

There is a common pattern to return `serializer.data` after an object has been successfully saved. However, if the `to_internal_value` returns a Django object (such as in a `PrimeryKeyRelatedField`), then the `Response` would produce this error:

```
raise TypeError(repr(o) + " is not JSON serializable")
```

A few solutions to this:

1. Run that data the other way, i.e. `FooSerializer(data=serializer.data)`
2. Manually replace it, i.e. `serializer.data['field'] = serializer.data['field'].pk`
3. Inherit something somewhere so that the Response can accept Django objects and default to `__str__` representation (but probably impossible unless there's a way for `isinstance` to know if it's a subclass of `models.Model`)
4. Don't return the [entire] object. The other side obviously has a copy of the data they sent, so there's no reason to send back the fields that weren't changed by the server.

Which of these solutions is most Pythonic, or is there a better solution not listed here?

Answer (score 0):

> There is a common pattern to return serializer.data after an object has been successfully saved.

No, this may be a common anti-pattern.

It returns serializer.validated_data which is different.

Comment: Sorry, are you saying I should be using `serializer.validated_data` instead of `serializer.data`?

Comment: If you're saving a Django object, you're deserializing. See http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#deserializing-objects